# error from drupalroot

Tags: 7

We have a live system.

[image: screenshot as below]

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
define ('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd ());
```

I couldn't log in with the command

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'D:/www/webhosting/o3800_7Z55V5Hop2Ff/wwwroot/vts/')
```

I changed it this way

I entered the site but the page is broken as it appears in the photo

I request help on this subject, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!   We are here to help. But for this to happen we need narrowly scoped, detailed and reproducible problems. So what do we need to do to run into the same error? What have you done before the error occurred? Please edit your question and include all necessary information. Please don't include links to your live site as they are worthless for demonstration purpose for future readers as soon as your problem got fixed. Please also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, will be better if you host a Drupal site on the separate domain/subdomain.

About your error, seems you forget copy all files (for example a folder with themes).

About the DRUPAL_ROOT constant, you shouldn't change it.

Comment: available in the theme folder, installed.

Comment: Except for the drupal_root index file, no other places are defined, right?

Comment: Maybe you have some specific changes in your sites/default/settings.php file.
Generally the index.php shouldn't change.

Comment: Please don't use answers for comments or clarification.